# Haskell polymorphic function Using Either Left Right

Tags: haskell, either, polymorphic-functions

I'm new to Haskell. I have the types:

```
type Variable = String
type Value = Float
type EvalError = [Variable]
type EvalResult = Either EvalError Value
```

And I want to create a function that I'll use a function to use it on 2 `EvalResult` types, and get a `EvalResult` accordingly.
If I get 2 Value types, I want to use the function on them (sum/sub for example), and If I'll get EvalError I want to return the EvalError.

What I did:

```
evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c
evalResultOp f (Left a) (Left b) = Left (a ++ b)
evalResultOp f (Left a) (Right b) = Left a
evalResultOp f (Right a) (Left b) = Left b
evalResultOp f (Right a) (Right b) = Right (f a b)
```

The error:

```
hs3.hs:46:34: error:
    • Expecting one fewer arguments to ‘EvalResult’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘EvalResult’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c)
                        -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c
   |
46 | evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    hs3.hs:46:50: error:
        • Expecting one fewer arguments to ‘EvalResult’
          Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘EvalResult’ has kind ‘*’
        • In the type signature:
            evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c)
                            -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c
       |
    46 | evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    hs3.hs:46:66: error:
        • Expecting one fewer arguments to ‘EvalResult’
          Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘EvalResult’ has kind ‘*’
        • In the type signature:
            evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c)
                            -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c
       |
    46 | evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c    |
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oops I added the error

Comment: The problem is your type synonyms are not polymorphic. What are you trying to do with this code? It's unclear.

Comment: Check http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses -> Kinds and some type-foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you define your `EvalResult` type as:

```
type EvalResult = Either EvalError Value
```

since `Either` is a *type* constructor, that takes two types, this means that you have constructed a type now (without any type parameters). If you write a function with type signature `(a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c`, then Haskell thus will eventually have to construct types `EvalResult a ~ Either EvalError Value a`, and since `Either` only takes two type parameters, this makes no sense.

My guess is that you want to define

```
type EvalResult a = Either EvalError a
```

or shorter:

```
type EvalResult = Either EvalError
```

Now `EvakResult` thus acts like a type constructor that can take one type parameter, and then the function indeed works over types.

We can make the implementation more compact by writing:

```
import Control.Monad(liftM2)

evalResultOp :: (a -> b -> c) -> EvalResult a -> EvalResult b -> EvalResult c
evalResultOp f (Left a) (Left b) = Left (a ++ b)
evalResultOp f x y = liftM2 f x y
```

[**`liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2) is a function that works over monadic types `m`. `Either a` is a monadic type, it is defined as:

> ```
> instance Monad (Either a) where
>     return = Right
>     (>>=) (Right x) f = f x
>     (>>=) (Left l) _ = Left l
> ```

`liftM2` is implemented as:

> ```
> liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
> liftM2 f xm ym = do
>     x <- mx
>     y <- my
>     return (f x y)
> ```

which is syntactical sugar for:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 f xm ym = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= \y -> return (f x y))
```

So basically we evaluate `mx >>= (...)` by checking if `mx` is a `Right`, if it is a `Left`, we return the content of the `Left`. Since we already handled the case with two `Left`s, that case is no longer possible, so we know that the second `EvalResult` is a `Right`, in that case we thus return the first `Left`. In case `mx` is a `Right x`, we now inspect `my >>= (..)` and check the state of `my`. If `my` is a `Left`, we again return that `Left`, otherwise, we return the `return (f x y)`, since `return` for an `Either a` monad, is actually `Right`, we thus wrap the content of `f x y` in the `Right` data constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a hard time understanding the use of `liftM2` in your implementation. Any chance you can say how would you implement it without the use of `liftM2`?

Comment: @sheldonzy The same way you did in your attempt. liftM2 just happens to implement the last 3 cases for you.